# Get data if property exists in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a db with 25000 users. And I need to grab the data of the users, which have certain property in their account. Like this:

```
let users = arrayFromObject(await firebase.database().ref('Users')
    .orderByChild('transactions')
    .once('value').then(r => r.val()).catch(e => console.log(e)));
console.log(users);
users = users.filter(u => {
    if (u.transactions) {
        return u;
    }
});
console.log(users);
```

And this works. But it turns out, only 630 users have said property. How can only get the users who have the `transactions` property? I was thinking about something like `orderByChild('transactions').exists()` but this function doesn't exist as far as I know.

How can I get only the users who have a `transactions` field in their account, and filter them on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it! This is what I did:

```
const users = arrayFromObject(await firebase.database().ref('Users')
    .orderByChild('transactions').startAt(1).once('value').then(r => r.val()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref("Users");

ref.orderByChild("transaction").on("value", function(snapshot) {
if(snapshot.exists()){
  console.log("the user has the transaction property");
    }
 });
```

Here the snapshot is at node `Users` then using `snapshot.exists()` you will be able to retrieve all the users that only have the `transaction` property.

You can change the database to this:

```
UserTransaction
         john  : true
         peter : true
```

or this one:

```
UserTransaction
         userId
           transaction : true
         userId
           trasansaction : true
```

This way you only retrieve the users that have the transaction property

Comment: But this still downloads the data to the machine right? I was trying to avoid excessive data usage

Comment: yes this will iterate in all the users node and get u the users that only have transaction so yes..You can create another node that only has the transaction property though

Comment: So there is no way to do the filtering on the server?

Comment: @AlexIronside changing the database to what I wrote in the answer is the only way

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's where you need to rethink your schema and use denormalization.  This way you will probably not have to make a query at all.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to do something like this. I'll leave the question open for a couple of days though in case a better answer appears.